# Regular expression issue

Tags: regex, linux, grep

may be this is newbie question, but I must ask it!
In general I'm understand regular expressions, but I don't understand, why this one:

```
^.{8}[[:blank:]]{2}
```

works on this line:

```
prelink: /lib/libkeyutils-1.2.so: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
```

in this grep command:

```
echo "prelink: /lib/libkeyutils-1.2.so: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking" | grep -v '^.\{8\}[[:blank:]]\{2\}'
```

where:

```
The                says "beggining of line"  
The .{8}           says "any eight characters"  
The [[:blank:]]{2} says "any two space characters"
```

So ^.{8} match "prelink:", when [[:blank:]]{2} need matching "  " (two spaces), but we have only " " (one space)...
So why this work at all, and if this work why this one:

```
^.{8}[[:blank:]]{1}
```

doesn't work?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `grep` with the `-v` option which causes it to print lines which *don't*  match. Remove the `-v` and it will work as you expect.

```
grep --help
...
   -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I was sure that -v is: "using regular expressions"

Comment: @rodnower: No, it's the "grep" part that means that. :D